# Uploading file to Server using JSP

Tags: apache, jsp

i was searching for a way to upload a file to server and found the following code ..

```
       File file ;
   int maxFileSize = 5000 * 1024;
   int maxMemSize = 5000 * 1024;
   ServletContext context = pageContext.getServletContext();
   String filePath = context.getInitParameter("file-upload");

   // Verify the content type
   String contentType = request.getContentType();
   if ((contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {

      DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
      // maximum size that will be stored in memory
      factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
      // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
      factory.setRepository(new File("/user2/tst/test"));

      // Create a new file upload handler
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
      // maximum file size to be uploaded.
      upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );
      try{ 
         // Parse the request to get file items.
         List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

         // Process the uploaded file items
         Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

         out.println("<html>");
         out.println("<head>");
         out.println("<title>JSP File upload</title>");  
         out.println("</head>");
         out.println("<body>");
         while ( i.hasNext () ) 
         {
            FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
            if ( !fi.isFormField () )   
            {
            // Get the uploaded file parameters
            String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
            String fileName = fi.getName();
            boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
            long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
            // Write the file
            if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
            file = new File( filePath + 
            fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
            }else{
            file = new File( filePath + 
            fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
            }
            fi.write( file ) ;
            out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + filePath + 
            fileName + "<br>");
            }
         }
         out.println("</body>");
         out.println("</html>");
      }catch(Exception ex) {
         System.out.println(ex);
      }
   }else{
      out.println("<html>");
      out.println("<head>");
      out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
      out.println("</head>");
      out.println("<body>");
      out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>"); 
      out.println("</body>");
      out.println("</html>");
   }
```

this code is working perfectly fine .. the only problem i am facing is , the file that is updated is getting stored in apache/bin folder ..

for this it was specified to add the following code to web.xml that is available in ROOT/WEB-INF

```
<context-param> 
    <description>Location to store uploaded file</description> 
    <param-name>file-upload</param-name> 
    <param-value>
         /user2/tst
     </param-value> 
</context-param>
```

even after this the file is getting stored in bin folder ..

i needed some help in this regard .. thanks in advance ..

Comment: Shouldn't you configure the `DiskFileItemFactory` with `file-upload` parameter as well?

Comment: please refer to http://www.journaldev.com/1964/servlet-upload-file-and-download-file-example for an example